# How should I model a relationship like "is contained in x with label y"?

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I'm trying to represent the following real world situation:

- "Document Alfred" contains the following annexes: "Document Zoey" as
  "Annex 1" and "Image 1" as "Annex 2"
- "Document Betty" contains the following annexes: "Song Rocky" as "Annex A" and "Document Zoey" as "Annex B"

I expected this to be fairly straightforward, but instead I ended up in making a mess, even to the point of having:

- A class "Document"
- A class "AnnexionID"
- An inverse functional object property "identifiesAnnexOf"
- An inverse functional object property "identifiesAsAnnex"
- Two inverse object properties for the latter two
- An object property "hasAnnex", which is a subproperty of the transitive one "hasPart", plus its inverse property "isAnnexOf".

This looks over-complicated to me, but is it? I would expect this to be a typical design pattern. What is (are) the relevant best practices?

Comment: This question has had very few views.  Since Protege is used for OWL ontologies, I've added the [tag:owl] tag, which will probably help to get some more visibility.

Comment: It doesn't have to be complex, although your question could use some clarification. Are you still online?

Comment: Hi Chris, still here. 
I would be glad to clarify

Comment: And, BTW - thanks Joshua for correcting the tag!